# Scrollbar Removal

Tags: mobile, scrollbar

I can't figure out how to remove the scroll bar from [my website](http://theweekndchat.com/).

I've looked up ways of doing it on SO but with no luck. It just keeps staying in the box.

I also want to be scrollable but just without the actual scroll bar visible from computers.
(It's not visible via mobile devices which is okay)

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard cross-browser CSS code you can use to render scroll bars invisible. However, you can put your `<div id="shoutbox_data">` element inside another `<div>` element with an `id` field like `"shoutbox_wrapper"`, set the CSS `overflow` property of the wrapper element to `hidden`, and then use JavaScript to automatically resize the wrapper element so it covers up the scrollbox. The idea comes from Jan Bilek, and you can find the JavaScript to accomplish this [on his blog](http://www.simplyeasy.cz/blog/2012/scrollable-textarea-without-scrollbar/).

Comment: It still shows the scrollbar when I do that :/ Did you try it in the chrome console?